# How to get "base" object from Exposed ResultRow

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-exposed

I'm defining an inner join as follows (done like this since, as far as I can tell, Exposed does not support additional values besides the composite primary key in the intermediate table):

```kotlin
val settingOrganisationList = (OrganisationTable innerJoin SettingOrganisationTable innerJoin SettingTable)
    .select { SettingOrganisationTable.organisationId eq organisation.id }
```

This join works fine, but I want to call functions on the Organisation, SettingOrganisation, and Setting objects using .map{ }, and I'm not sure how to get these.

I can get the individual object properties like this just fine:

```kotlin
val settingOrganisationList = (OrganisationTable innerJoin SettingOrganisationTable innerJoin SettingTable)
    .select { SettingOrganisationTable.organisationId eq organisation.id }
    .map {
        println(it[OrganisationTable.name])
    }
```

but I'm not sure how to get the entire OrganisationTable object.

Sorry if this question has been answered before, I haven't been able to word it in a way that gets me useful results from Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check [the wiki](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/wiki/DAO#read-entity-with-a-join-to-another-table) on how to wrap query and get entities.
If you'd like to make it in a `map` call you can use:

```kotlin
(OrganisationTable innerJoin SettingOrganisationTable innerJoin SettingTable)
    .select { SettingOrganisationTable.organisationId eq organisation.id }
    .map { Organization.wrapRow(it) }
```

Comment: That seems to do the trick, thanks! Can't believe I somehow missed that bit of the docs, I swear I did read them :)